# Magento 2: How I can use category DataProvider in Admin Grid

Tags: magento2, category, uicomponent, category-listing, data-provider

I am trying to add Category Grid in Magento 2

I created A grid and add Dataprovider

> Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\DataProvider

Here is Code of My DataProvider

```
<dataSource name="vendor_module_categoryimages_listing">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">vendor_module_categoryimages_listing_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">entity_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
                    <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
```

I am getting an Error as Follows

> The "componentType" configuration parameter is required for the
>   "general" component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update your **dataSource** content with this content

```
<dataSource name="vendor_module_categoryimages_listing">
    <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
        <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\DataProvider</argument>
        <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">vendor_module_categoryimages_listing_data_source</argument>
        <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">entity_id</argument>
        <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </argument>
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</dataSource>
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Is above solution helps you, or you are still getting any errors there ?

Comment: sorry its not working for me